# NSMutable array, do not retain the added object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a UITextField called `txtvwEmail`. i am adding the text from `txtvwEmail.text` to the Array `pastUrls` but after adding the next text it remove the first text. Im using the code

```
if (![pastUrls containsObject:txtvwEmail.text]) {
    [pastUrls addObject:txtvwEmail.text];
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you were trying to do / expecting?

Comment: addObject *will* increase the retain count. What kind of object is `txtvwEmail.text`?

Comment: i am adding the text from txtvwEmail.text in the Array pastUrls but after adding the next text it remove the first text

Comment: Have you tried casting txtvwEMail.text to an local NSString variable (ie, NSString* emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", txtvwEmail.text]) and then [pastUrls addObject:emailString];? stringWithFormat is an autoreleased helper, so there shouldn't be any issues with memory leaks there.

Comment: What count? You mean the number of objects in the array? How are you determining the count? `[array count]`?

Comment: yes the it shows only 1 NSLog(@"%d",[postarray count]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rely on the basics of the language and frameworks. The array DOES RETAIN the object, however, it could be:

1. pastUrls is nil -> no retain
2. somewhere in the code .text is released (or autoreleased) and the
   count is yet the same

Also, you can't really be sure [obj retainCount] return the correct value. To diagnose the real problem, revise the code or post it here so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
//this should be outside of ur all loops
NSMutableArray *pastUrls=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//remove this line
//NSMutableArray *pastUrls=[NSMutableArray array];

if (![pastUrls containsObject:txtvwEmail.text]) {
    [pastUrls addObject:txtvwEmail.text];
}

NSLog(@"pastUrls : %@ \n\n",pastUrls);
```